# add items to the list of an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class bag:

    items = []

    def add_item(self,x):
        self.items.append(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    bag1 = bag()
    bag2 = bag()

    bag1.add_item("water")
    print(bag2.items)
```

I'm trying to add water to the bag1 but I have no idea why "bag1.add_item("water")" will affect bag2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class bag:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self,x):
        self.items.append(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    bag1 = bag()
    bag2 = bag()

    bag1.add_item("water")
    print(bag2.items)
```

All you have to do is add `def __init__(self)`.
Declaring the variables inside the class declaration makes them "class" members and not instance members. Declaring them inside the `__init__` method makes sure that a new instance of the members is created alongside every new instance of the object, which is the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: How come non-iterables such as an integer defined as a class member are able to be changed for each object without affecting any of the other objects while this list does change if a single object appends it?

Comment: If you initialize class variable after creating object then class variable became instance variable. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/W2MWygX9cc/ you can run this code for verification.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that `items = []` has been declared as a class variable, so all instances of that class will share the same memory location for `items`. For each instance to have it's own `items` list, you need to use the keyword `self`, something like:

```
class bag:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self,x):
        self.items.append(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    bag1 = bag()
    bag2 = bag()

    bag1.add_item("water")
    print(bag2.items)
```

For additional details, refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The following code should fix the problem:

```py
class bag:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, x):
        self.items.append(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bag1 = bag()
    bag2 = bag()

    bag1.add_item("water")
    print(bag2.items)
```